# How To detect a specific Extension that communicate with my webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, window

In my webpage i want to make a script to detect a specific extension that manipulate my code

I've already tried the following in my webpage

```
async function tst(){
    debugger;
    window.addEventListener("PassToBackground", function(evt) {
        var blockedExID="bjnkkhimoaclnddigpphpgkfgeggokam";
    if (!chrome.runtime) {
        // Chrome 20-21
        chrome.runtime = chrome.extension;
    } else if(!chrome.runtime.onMessage) {
        // Chrome 22-25
        chrome.runtime.onMessage = chrome.extension.onMessage;
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage = chrome.extension.sendMessage;
        chrome.runtime.onConnect = chrome.extension.onConnect;
        chrome.runtime.connect = chrome.extension.connect;
    }
    var runtimeOrExtension = chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage ?
                         'runtime' : 'extension';

   var reponse= chrome[runtimeOrExtension].sendMessage(blockedExID,{ message: "version" },{
        function (reply) {
            if (reply) {
            alert(reply);
            }
    }
    
});
chrome[runtimeOrExtension].sendMessage({greeting: 'hello'});
    
        }, false);
}
```

but chrome.runtime is undefiled

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If chrome.runtime is undefined then this extension cannot be detected via this method. Your only hope is that the extension adds something to DOM or uses web_accessible_resources in its manifest.json.